# Can we apply css React Bootstrap Navbar?

Tags: react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-nav

my question is that I have a navbar import from react bootstrap it's work perfect but on full browser screen but after responsive means when max-width is 360px navbar is not work properly I want to style my navbar inline after responsive can anybody tell me how can I style my navbar , thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, Just go to the inspect element Dev tools in chrome and note down the nav bar class you want to edit. Then in your CSS or SASS write that class and its children you want to edit and fix/change the CSS. It's basically overwriting the pre made CSS with your own.